# Completing an image in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I have created and finished editing my image in illustrator. It is a background of a flag with some shapes on it. How do I make it one image so the shapes aren't separate from the flag and I can move it around the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Group the elements (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) or convert to a symbol (<kbd>F8</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you - I had done it in the past but ages ago!